# Only display ForeignKeys that pass a condition in Django.

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I have the following code:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    is_finished = models.BooleanField("Is this book finished?")
    description = models.TextField("What's your book about? Think of this as the back cover")
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
    #book_cover = should take an img as input


class Place(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Chapter(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

The last class is giving my trouble. I want to be able to choose from a Place only if that Place is also in the same Book as my Chapter will be.

How can I accomplish this? I'm extremely new to Django and programming in general, sorry if my question is easily answered. I've tried searching through the Django docs but nothing seemed to work.

Comment: what you have at first? book or chapter or place?

Comment: What are you asking precisely? If I understood right: I first should be able to create a Book (with a title, a description and the boolean is_finished). That works well. Then Place defines all the different places that book can happen in (for example: Minessota, New York and Japan). The the chapter is basically the text + which book it belongs to + the place where it happens.

Comment: so, if you need list of all places from book: `place_list = Place.objects.filter(book=book_that_youve_created)`

Comment: Yes, but how do I apply that to the class? I can't replace book_that_ive_created with a constant, it should be able to know in which book "Chapter" is!

Answer (score 0):

The `book` field in the model `Chapter` can be deducted from the `place` field, so you should discard it, then access to it by `place.book`.